# java to c# how to do custom painting in a panel

Tags: c#, java, paint

in java when you want to do custom painting in a panel, you usually override the paint() function.

now i am looking for the corresponding function to override in a C# panel.

also i would be thankful for a short samplecode to do some painting. like draw a circle or something.

thanks a lot!

edit: ok thanks for your answers! i have an additional question on this: what is the preferred method to manually trigger a repaint? for example i want my red circle to be green suddenly. how do i make the call to OnPaint()?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You override the OnPaint method. Here's a quick example of drawing a circle in C#:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
  Graphics gfx = pe.Graphics;
  using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue))
  {
    gfx.DrawEllipse(pen, 10,10,10,10);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Override the [`OnPaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) method.

There's a [simple example here](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial50_Drawing-with-Csharp.html), and searching for [`OnPaint tutorial C#`](http://www.google.com/search?q=onpaint+tutorial+c%23) gets lots of hits.